# How to read json value of a response in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, parsing

This is the script part of one of my widgets in a website.Anyway when textboxes of "inp" class has a changed value the code sends all the parameters to a webservice which looks through database and return records as json.My problem is i dont know how to get values in json response.I'm trying to add new divs to res12 div as results which should come from the json.I was able to create the divs but values are undefined and also the script runs for multiple times and i dont understand why.I need your help.thanks in advance.
the json response

[{"description":"sent for a meeting","date":"19.02.2012 21:34:26","lid":"6","companyname":"M&L","personname":"jack ferrel","email":"jacky@ml.com","fax":"123123","phone":"345345","industryname":"finance","teamname":"w12et","sender":"jack ferrel","statusname":"waiting"}]

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

          var typingTimer;               
          var doneTypingInterval = 5000;
          $(document).ready(function () {
              $(".inp").keyup(function () {
                    typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
                });
                $(".inp").keydown(function () {
                    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
                });

            });

            function doneTyping() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "letter.ashx",
                    data: { CompanyName: $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").val(), PersonName: $("#<%=TextBox3.ClientID%>").val(), Email: $("#<%=TextBox5.ClientID%>").val() },
                    dataType: "application/json",
                    success: function (msg) {

                        var newdiv = $('<div class="e"><div></div><div>'+CompanyName+'</div><div>'+Sender+'</div><div>1</div><div>2</div></div> ');

                        $('#res12').append(newdiv);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Your question is meaningless if you don't show the JSON structure returned by your server script.

Comment: i've added the json response of a single line

Comment: @DarinDimitrov you can look at the json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing `undefined` in the new divs created because `CompanyName` and `Sender` are not defined. If they are part of ajax response the you use `msg.CompanyName` and `msg.Sender`. Try this.

```
        function doneTyping() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "letter.ashx",
                data: { CompanyName: $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").val(), PersonName: $("#<%=TextBox3.ClientID%>").val(), Email: $("#<%=TextBox5.ClientID%>").val() },
                dataType: "application/json",
                success: function (msg) {

                    var newdiv = $('<div class="e"><div></div><div>'+msg.CompanyName+'</div><div>'+msg.Sender+'</div><div>1</div><div>2</div></div> ');

                    $('#res12').append(newdiv);
                }
            });
        }
```

**Update:**

The json you posted in the question has `companyname` and not `CompanyName`, same for `sender`. Remember that JavaScript is case sensitive so you have to use `companyname` and `sender` in your code to get there values.

Comment: Oh sorry i mistyped it here.It is msg.CompanyName and msg.Sender.The problem is it adds 5 divs and it is still undefined.though i can see the json when i use alert(msg)